# Parsing XML one time only on 1st startup

Tags: android, parsing

I'm currently using a Parser and it parses every time the onCreate gets called.
My parser uses an XML file that's located in my assetfolder.

Is there any chance that I can make it parse only once, instead of every time I rotate the screen or restart the application?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persist a flag using the Preferences system the first time you complete a parse, and check this each time before parsing again. Do all this in your OnCreate() method.

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!settings.getBoolean("parsed", false)) {
        parseTheXML();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("parsed",  true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

There are other ways but this has the advantage of working across app reloads/phone power cycles - assuming that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work great, and I do indeed want to make my app drain least battery possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 answers to this question.  The easy one first:

If you only want this to happen once, create a static boolean in your main activity and set it to true when the XML is parsed in.  Then use:

```
if(!isParsed)
    XML.parse();
```

The more complete answer to this question is to make sure you are handling configuration changes correctly.

I suggest you read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState) on how to implement configuration change handling.  You should be able to solve this problem "the Android way" by implementing this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But he should save the state of `isParsed` permanently (e. g. with `SharedPreferences`) before leaving the activity and check the value every time the app starts.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to parse the XML in once per application lifecycle, not once in the entire installed lifetime of the application.  If that is the case, then sharedpreferences is the way to go.

Comment: I do indeed want it only to parse once per installed app :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a preference.  Something like -

```
void setIsAppOpened() {
    editor.putBoolean(APP_OPENED, true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Set it in your onCreate(). Then, also add the following code to check if the preference exists.

```
if (!prefs.contains(APP_OPENED))
    {
        //parse the XML
        setIsAppOpened();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your XML in a "Application" object and have it accessible from there. Check out the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html